# apply class to one ajax loaded img if that img src is currently present on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here's the question: 
I have a list of images that get loaded via .load( onto a div on my page

```
$('.widget-top').live("click", function() {
    $(".area").load("/galleries/ #projects > li a");
});
```

they load with this structure:

```
<a href="#"><img src="photoA.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="#"><img src="photoB.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="#"><img src="photoC.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="#"><img src="photoD.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="#"><img src="photoE.jpg" /> </a>
```

I click on the image and the src is retrived and added to a form value like so:

```
$("#widgets-right .area a").live("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if ( i === 2){
        alert('added to project 1 if you want to add more projects just click the button below');
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(".title").val(title);
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".link").val(link);
        var img = $("img", this).attr('src');
        $(".img").val(img);
        var imgexample = $("img", this).attr('src');
        $(".gallery_one").attr("src", imgexample);
    }
    else{
        i --;
        alert('added to project'+i); 
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('.title'+i).val(title);
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.link'+i).val(link);
        var img = $('img', this).attr('src');
        $('.img'+i).val(img);
        var imgexample = $('img', this).attr('src');
        $('.gallery_one'+i).attr("src", imgexample);
        i++;
    }
});
```

and as you can see from this line `$(this).toggleClass('selected');` it's toggling a class when clicked. 
up to here all is good, my problem occurs when i save my form and it get's refreshed via ajax. The images with the selected class now no longer have the selected class because they have been refreshed. 
I do have  input fields with the current src's of the selected images on page. Is there any way to search through those fields and reapply the class if the src'sin the input fields  match the src's of the images that where reloaded via the .load() call? 
Chris

Comment: `live` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/), use `on` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the currently selected item in a variable and after the images are loaded you need to assign the class back

```
var selected; // it should be in a context shared between both the methods

$("#widgets-right .area a").live("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if ( i === 2){
        alert('added to project 1 if you want to add more projects just click the button below');
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(".title").val(title);
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".link").val(link);
        var img = $("img", this).attr('src');
        $(".img").val(img);
        selected = img;
        var imgexample = $("img", this).attr('src');
        $(".gallery_one").attr("src", imgexample);

    }   
    else{  
        i --;
        alert('added to project'+i); 
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('.title'+i).val(title);
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.link'+i).val(link);
        var img = $('img', this).attr('src');
        $('.img'+i).val(img);
        selected = img;
        var imgexample = $('img', this).attr('src');
        $('.gallery_one'+i).attr("src", imgexample);
        i ++;
    }    
});

$('.widget-top').live("click", function() {
    $(".area").load("/galleries/ #projects > li a", function(){
        if(selected){
        $(".area").find('img[src="' + selected + '"]').closest('a').toggleClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```